# Node-webkit Browser Plugin

Tags: node.js, browser, cross-browser, node-webkit, npapi

**Description of the Problem**

As NPAPI plugins will be deprecated in Chrome (maybe in Firefox too soon) and being part of a project ([WebChimera](http://www.webchimera.org/)) that is based on an NPAPI plugin. I've been thinking of different solutions to keep NPAPI support in browsers. (as porting this plugin to NaCL is currently impossible, but the plugin can be used in a frozen version of node-webkit that currently supports NPAPIs)

So I was wondering if it is possible for a browser page to open a node-webkit app on the user's PC, then using JS with/without jQuery to send data about the html element where the Node-Webkit window (with always on top set) should be to the app (maybe through a websocket) to always position it there.

I know I can get a html element's size, position in JavaScript, I also know I can track the scroll of the user and browser tab changes to do the necessary changes to the window size, position and visibility.

**The Question**

The thing that truly stops me from even attempting this is how would I know when a browser is not fullscreen, and how would I know the browser's position on the screen if it is not fullscreen either from the on page JS or from node-webkit directly. Another thing that should be a concern is what screen is the browser window on.

Am I the only one that has thought of such an endeavor with node-webkit, are there any open source projects attempting this?

Any thoughts or comments on this would be greatly appreciated as a solution to this would not only save NPAPI plugins in the near future but will also open a world where Node-Webkit can also be used as a viable solution to build browser plugins too. :)

Answer (score 2):

This would involve a lot of painful hackery.  You'd have to solve most of these issues on all platforms independently and rely on a lot of implementation details.

As a possible alternative, check out the [plans for FireBreath 2.0](http://www.firebreath.org/x/kQCt) which will support plugins which can be loaded via NPAPI, ActiveX, and Native Messaging via a new protocol called FireWyrm.  Currently there is no drawing support when using the FireWyrm interface and only Native Messaging is supported.  Additionally it's not quite finished, though I'm getting close =]

Comment: Thanks taxilian, can't wait to see it! I'm a big fan of your work. :) I would although leave this question open for the moment, as a solution to it will be more then just a possible solution to saving NPAPI's, but also creating node.js based browser plugins. I am aware it requires painful hackery, and a lot of very precise tweaking, but it would let web developers create browser plugins.. which seems right in so many ways.. :)

Comment: @tixilian, Thank you for your answer. And if you already here, I want ask you another question :) What do you think about creating framework like FireBreath to simplify develop of node.js/io.js c++ addons for Node-Webkit/NW.js? .

Comment: I'd love to see an adapter that would allow you to use FireBreath's JSAPIAuto with a node.js module; it would also almost certainly be possible to use some sort of websocket interface with the page, a node.js module, and the new FireWyrm protocol to have a browser plugin which would essentially execute server-side but the interface would be the same.  It would be a bit slower, however =]

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to use libvlc to play video directly on NW.js/Electron page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webchimera.js

What this project is: it's low level (written in C++) addon which use libvlc and allow decode video frames to JS ArrayBuffer object. In turn this ArrayBuffer object could be drawn on HTML5 canvas directly or with WebGL. This project use Node.js/V8 API directly and not use NPAPI at all, so will live even after NPAPI deprecation. Another good thing - perfomance of this (espesially if use WebGL) is comparable with original VLC player perfomance.

Simple usage example available at: https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player